# How to debug NSAllowsArbitraryLoads not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, app-transport-security

I'm having problems loading youku.com videos inside a UIWebView in my app.  I'm pretty sure it's due to App Transport Security because replacing the embed with an HTTPS URL works fine.  There is, of course, no HTTPS equivalent URL, because China.

I've read about the various NSAppTransportSecurity settings.  My first instinct of course was to try NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to at least verify the problem, but that didn't work.  Then I followed various online guides that show how to NSExceptionDomains like you're supposed to, but that's not working either.

And now I'm stuck.  FWIW, I'm catching URL loading errors like this:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    ...
    if (error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"NSURLErrorCancelled: URL %@ error %@", urlString, error);
    }
}
```

For the moment I'm using a dummy test URL exon.name, and that produces:

```
2015-12-02 15:47:22.312 ZaoMengShe[81707:903426] NSURLErrorCancelled: URL https://dev1.zaomengshe.com/c/54260 error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://exon.name/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://exon.name/}
```

To confirm, -999 is the error when App Transport Security does this, right?  (It's not a very informative error!)

The other thing, as noted in e.g. [NSAllowsArbitraryLoads not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951267/nsallowsarbitraryloads-not-working), is that you have to edit the "Info.plist" file.  I don't have such a file.  I have "ZaoMengShe-Info.plist" ("ZaoMengShe" being the name of my app).  But none of the questions show an actual screenshot including the file name, so for all I know everyone's Info.plist file actually includes the name of the app and that's normal.  Am I mistaken?

[image: App Transport Security Settings]
[image: Info.plist settings]

Comment: error code `-999` stands for the `kCFURLErrorCancelled` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is working fine in this case.  My problem is I'm hitting another restriction.  In the new security policy, you're not allowed to load insecure (HTTP) active content inside a secure (HTTPS) page.  This is true in the browser as well as UIWebView.  There doesn't seem to be any way to turn this behaviour off.

Here's some extra logs to show the error message with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads switched off and then on.  It fails either way, but I get an extra error message in the first case:

```
2015-12-07 17:58:10.589 TestWeb[13583:4566542] about to load url https://dev1.zaomengshe.com/c/54260
2015-12-07 17:58:15.966 TestWeb[13583:4569606] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2015-12-07 17:58:16.045 TestWeb[13583:4566542] failed to load
2015-12-07 17:58:40.879 TestWeb[13583:4566542] NSURLErrorCancelled: error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://exon.name/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://exon.name/}
2015-12-07 17:58:40.895 TestWeb[13583:4569023] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2015-12-07 17:58:41.878 TestWeb[13583:4569606] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2015-12-07 17:58:41.884 TestWeb[13583:4566542] finished load urlString: https://dev1.zaomengshe.com/c/54260

2015-12-07 17:54:57.431 TestWeb[13503:4532874] about to load url https://dev1.zaomengshe.com/c/54260
2015-12-07 17:55:02.339 TestWeb[13503:4532874] failed to load
2015-12-07 17:55:15.310 TestWeb[13503:4532874] NSURLErrorCancelled: error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://exon.name/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://exon.name/}
2015-12-07 17:55:15.313 TestWeb[13503:4533886] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2015-12-07 17:55:16.210 TestWeb[13503:4534307] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
2015-12-07 17:55:16.653 TestWeb[13503:4532874] finished load urlString: https://dev1.zaomengshe.com/c/54260
```

In my case I was loading an insecure youku video in an iframe, and iframes count as active content.  So there's no way it can be made to work.  Youku doesn't provide HTTPS content.

The solution turns out to be elegantly simple: move the entire app back to the HTTP version of my site and keep the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads flag.  Hooray!  That was a fun experiment with HTTPS everyone, thanks for that.  Be sure to get back to me when it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your target settings. Name of your .plist file must be in Packaging section of Build Settings in parameter named Info.plist file. It must be a relative path to .plist file from folder containing project file.

UPDATE:
Your error message contains URL https://dev1.zaomengshe.com/c/54260
If you open this URL from browser you will see it's https certificate isn't trusted. So cancelling of your requests is not due to App Transport Security, but UIWebView untrusted certificate security.

There is one solution for this case. Before UIWebView will start loading request from untrusted URL you must make it trusted for it. URL loading system caches your requests. And when you programatically tell it to download anyway, UIWebView starts loading from this URL.

Here is a code snippet i used in my project:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"] && ![request.URL.absoluteString hasPrefix:[AppData sharedInstance].serverBaseUrl] && ![self.authenticatedUrls containsObject:request.URL.absoluteString]){
        __weak NBTransferFromCardConfirmationVC * weakself = self;
        NBInsecureSslAuth * auth=[NBInsecureSslAuth new];
        [auth authInsecureUrlRequet:request
        success:^{
            [weakself.authenticatedUrls addObject:request.URL.absoluteString];
            [webView loadRequest:request];
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            [weakself.authenticatedUrls addObject:request.URL.absoluteString];
            [webView loadRequest:request];
//            showErrorWithTitle(@"Error", error.localizedDescription);
        }];
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Source code for NBInsecureSslAuth:

```
@implementation NBInsecureSslAuth

- (void)authInsecureUrlRequet:(NSURLRequest*)request success:(void (^)(void))success failure:(void (^)(NSError * error))failure{

AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:request.URL];

client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate=YES;

[client setDefaultHeader:@"User-Agent" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ (iOS %@)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleExecutableKey] ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey], [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey], [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString]]];

NSMutableURLRequest * authRequest=[client requestWithMethod:request.HTTPMethod path:@"" parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation=
[client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:authRequest
                                success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                    if(success){
                                        success();
                                    }
                                }
                                failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                    if(failure){
                                        failure(error);
                                    }
                                }];

[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];


}


@end
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that clarifies that!  I've attached a screenshot, it looks to me as though I'm setting it all correctly.

Comment: OK as to the bad certificate... this of course is just my test environment.  I already imported the certificate to the simulator.  Without that, I can't load any data at all.  The fact that it can make AJAX requests successfully after I import the certificate suggests this isn't the problem.  Also, this problem exists on the live version of our app looking at the live site, which has a valid certificate.

Comment: Please, please consider that by allowing untrusted websites you open up your application to any hacker. Especially if you get errors from your _own_ website then the solution is to fix the website, not trust untrusted websites. Any hacker can redirect requests from your website to theirs, but they cannot forge certificates. By trusting untrusted sites, they don't need to forge anything.

Comment: Yes, the live site has valid credentials and when I get it working I'll tweak the settings appropriately.  For now, however, I have no way of affecting App Transport Security at all and nothing I do to any of those settings has any impact.  First I need to get it working!

Comment: ...that said.  Until a few months ago no-one seemed to consider HTTPS as anything more than a nice-to-have and the world kept turning.  Then Apple decides with very little notice that the vast majority of the web must now be switched off?  I've been evangelising HTTPS for our site for years and I've been gradually switching it on all of this year.  But now all of a sudden I have to get the whole thing finished RFN... why?  A whole bunch of people need to learn to chill, man.